# Ao mudar o estado do modal meu componente pai renderiza novamente

Tags: react, typescript, front-end

No componente pai eu faço um requisição que me devolve um trailer de filme. Ao clicar em Assistir trailer abre um modal que exibe o trailer do filme. Porém sempre que abro u fecho o modal, a requisição é feita novamente, o que é um sinal de que o componente pai possa estar sendo renderizado sempre que o estado do modal muda.

Código do modal:

```
 type YouTubeModalProps = {
 open: boolean;
 onClose: () => void;
 videoId: string;
};

const YouTubeModal = React.memo(({ open, onClose, videoId }: YouTubeModalProps) => {
 return (
   <Modal
     open={open}
     onClose={onClose}
     aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
     aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
     style={{
       display: "flex",
       alignItems: "center",
       justifyContent: "center",
       backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
     }}
   >
     <IframeWrapper>
       <IframeTitleWrapper>
         <IframeTitle>Reproduzir Trailer</IframeTitle>
         <IframeClose icon="ic:round-close" onClick={onClose} />
       </IframeTitleWrapper>
       <iframe
         width="100%"
         height="100%"
         src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`}
         title="YouTube video player"
         allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
         allowFullScreen
         style={{ border: "none", outline: "none" }}
       ></iframe>
     </IframeWrapper>
   </Modal>
 );
});

export default YouTubeModal;
```

Código do componente pai

```
  const ComponentePai = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const toggleModal = useCallback(() => {
    setOpen(prevState => !prevState);
  }, []);

  return (

    <>
      <Label onClick={toggleModal}>
         <Icon icon="solar:play-bold" inline /> Assista ao trailer
      </Label>
      <YouTubeModal
         open={open}
         onClose={toggleModal}
         videoId={trailerId}
       />
    </>
  )
}
export default ComponentePai
```

Quero evitar esse tipo de comportamento. Quero evitar evitar renderizações desnecessárias de modo que o componente pai seja renderizado apenas quando a página recarregar. Tentei fazer uso do `useCallback` e do `useMemo`, mas não funcionou, talvez eu esteja usando-os de forma errada